# Django Queryset - complex relationship parameter as variable?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a geographic object that is used in proximity searches.  That object is keyed to different other objects via various paths.

Examples:

```
  blog.geo_object
  user.profile.geo_object
  group.event.geo_object
```

Right now, i do a bounding box search, which strings like this:

```
radius_queryset = base_queryset.filter(
    user__profile__geo__lat__gte = bounding_box.lat_min,
    user__profile__geo__lat__lte = bounding_box.lat_max,
    user__profile__geo__lon__gte = bounding_box.lon_min,
    user__profile__geo__lon__lte = bounding_box.lon_max,
```

and then on other objects:

```
radius_queryset = base_queryset.filter(
    blog__geo__lat__gte = bounding_box.lat_min,
    blog__geo__lat__lte = bounding_box.lat_max,
    blog__geo__lon__gte = bounding_box.lon_min,
    blog__geo__lon__lte = bounding_box.lon_max,
)
```

This follows a general format of:

```
radius_queryset = base_queryset.filter(
    [lookup_path]__geo__lat__gte = bounding_box.lat_min,
    [lookup_path]__geo__lat__lte = bounding_box.lat_max,
    [lookup_path]__geo__lon__gte = bounding_box.lon_min,
    [lookup_path]__geo__lon__lte = bounding_box.lon_max,
)
# where lookup_path = "blog"  or "user__profile" in the two above examples
```

I'm writing enough of these (3 so far, more to come) to want to generalize the queries -- encapsulation being a good friend of maintainability and an ally in the fight against typo-bugs.

So, to my question:  short of using exec and eval (which just look ugly), is there a way to get the filter parameter name to sub-in a variable?  Am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`**kwargs` is your answer!

```
def generate_qs(lookup_path, bounding_box):
    return base_queryset.filter(**{
        lookup_path + '__geo__lat__gte' : bounding_box.lat_min,
        lookup_path + '__geo__lat__lte' : bounding_box.lat_max,
        lookup_path + '__geo__lon__gte' : bounding_box.lon_min,
        lookup_path + '__geo__lon__lte' : bounding_box.lon_max,
    })

radius_queryset = generate_qs('blog', bounding_box)
```

Comment: I've yet to wrap my head around **kwargs, but, I can see how that works.  Thanks!

Comment: @Ted, ** expands dictionary key - value pairs to keyword - argument pairs. `func(keyword=argument) == func(**{keyword:argument})`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Python's `**kwargs` syntax to put this nastiness away in a helper function. Something like:

```
def helper(lookup_path, bounding_box):
        return dict([ ("%s__geo__%s" % (lookup_path, lkup_left, ),
                       getattr(bounding_box, lkup_right), )
                     for lkup_left, lkup_right in
                     (("lat__gte", "lat_min", ),
                      ("lat__lte", "lat_max", ),
                      ("lon__gte", "lon_min", ),
                      ("lon__lte", "lon_max", ), 
                     ) ])

qs = base_queryset.filter(**helper(lookup_path, bounding_box))
```